# Bug/larva identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What do you think these could be?

[image]

The photo was taken today from the inside of a bin liner, which contained waste from fruit and vegetables (carrot skin, banana peel, salad leaves, etc.), and (normally) nothing of animal origin.

Size: about 3-4 mm (body length).

Location: Europe/Belgium.

Behaviour: did not seem to move at all, or only extremely slowly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly juveniles of the [Clausiliidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausiliidae) family, of which there are many, many varieties. I'm having trouble pinning down the exact one, as pics of adult snails dominate the web. Unless an expert comes along, perhaps you can look after some 'till they grow-up, then take another picture?

Comment: Thanks! So maybe they are not even insects... :D They did look like mini snails to me, when I saw the photo, but I did not mention that in the post, as I did not want to sound silly. That worked, didn't it(!). As for your suggestion to follow their development, hmm, I don't suppose they will get the chance to 'grow up', unfortunately :/, but I will ask.